# How to derive formula for emitter current flowing through Re?

Tags: transistors, amplifier, bjt, npn

[image]

Ie = Ve/Re

I was thinking about using that approach but i have been doubting myself if that is the right approach to go with, because then i have to express the emitter current in term of alpha and beta
Can anyone clear my doubt please?

Comment: With the other end of the emitter resistor at ground as shown, the emitter current pretty much has to be the emitter voltage divided by the emitter resistor. If you know any two values, you've got the third.

Comment: Can you elaborate more, please?

Comment: I can't, since I don't really follow what you really want to know.

Comment: This is easy to solve if we **assume** that R1 and R2 directly determine \$V_B\$ (so \$I_B\$ is so small it can be neglected). Then R1 and R2 are simply a voltage divider so from \$V_{cc}\$ we can derive \$V_B\$. Then **assume** \$V_{BE}\$ = 0.7 V, then we know \$V_E\$. Then we can find \$I_E\$. Then using \$\beta\$ derive \$I_B\$ and compare it to the current through R1, if \$I_B\$ is much smaller than I(R1) our first assumption was OK to make. If not then you need to re-calculate V(R1).

Comment: thanks @Bimpelrekkie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a full answer but much too long for a comment and should give you some pointers

We know \$ \beta = \dfrac{I_E}{I_B} \$, and \$ \alpha = \dfrac{I_C}{I_E} \$ so we can define \$ \alpha = \dfrac{\beta}{\beta+1} \$, we can ignore \$ \alpha \$.

Typically \$ \beta \ge 100 \$ and \$ V_{be} \approx 0.7 \text{V} \$.

We also know \$ I_E = \dfrac{V_E}{R_E} = \dfrac{V_B - V_{be}}{R_E}= \beta \cdot I_B\$

And Finally \$ I_B = \dfrac{V_{cc}-V_B}{R_1}-\dfrac{V_B}{R_2}\$

This gives us:

$$\dfrac{V_B - V_{be}}{R_E}= \beta \cdot \left( \dfrac{V_{cc}-V_B}{R_1}-\dfrac{V_B}{R_2} \right)  $$

The rest is just maths, solve for \$ V_B \$ and use \$ I_E = \dfrac{V_B - V_{be}}{R_E}\$ to get your answer.

I'll leave the rest as an exercise.

---

For most practical designs we assume \$ I_B = 0\$ which greatly simplifies this but I encourage you to try both to see how similar the results are.

Comment: This is what i needed thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the formulas as given by Warren Hill in his answer, I like to visualize the role of the emitter resistor RE and to show why is not too important to know the actual Vbe value (tolerances, uncertainties, temperature dependence). Instead, for calculation purposes we assume a fixed value of app 0.7 volts.
[image]

Comment: This gave me a more clear picture of the problem thanks